# Expression Must Have Pointer-To-Struct-Or-Union Type

Tags: c

I am passing dosHeader as a reference to the Test method, which should print out the ntHeader's signature. However, I am getting a compiler error under `*dosHeader->e_lfanew` - "expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type". I've tried casting it to (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER*), which does remove the compiler error but doesn't work. What am I misunderstanding?

```
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader;    

Test(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER *dosHeader)
{
    *dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)PEBytes;
    ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((LONG)*dosHeader + *dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    printf("%d", ntHeader->Signature);
}

void main()
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = 0;
    Test(&dosHeader);
}
```

Here is the structure definition

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {      // DOS .EXE header
    WORD   e_magic;                     // Magic number
    WORD   e_cblp;                      // Bytes on last page of file
    WORD   e_cp;                        // Pages in file
    WORD   e_crlc;                      // Relocations
    WORD   e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
    WORD   e_minalloc;                  // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_maxalloc;                  // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_ss;                        // Initial (relative) SS value
    WORD   e_sp;                        // Initial SP value
    WORD   e_csum;                      // Checksum
    WORD   e_ip;                        // Initial IP value
    WORD   e_cs;                        // Initial (relative) CS value
    WORD   e_lfarlc;                    // File address of relocation table
    WORD   e_ovno;                      // Overlay number
    WORD   e_res[4];                    // Reserved words
    WORD   e_oemid;                     // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    WORD   e_oeminfo;                   // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    WORD   e_res2[10];                  // Reserved words
    LONG   e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header
  } IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess `*dosHeader->e_lfanew` --> `dosHeader->e_lfanew`

Comment: Please show the definition of `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER`.

Comment: Added it  @WeatherVane

Comment: @M.M Unfortunately that did not fix it.

Comment: Oops, I mean `(*dosHeader)->e_lfanew`

Comment: @M.M That solved it! Not sure WHY exactly, I'm assuming order of operations?

Comment: `dosHeader` is pointer to a pointer so you need to dereference it twice to get the structure

Comment: Ah I saw, but all I was missing were those parenthesis around dosHeader. That's why I was wondering if it was an order of operations issue.